# Resolving time in NLP

Tags: nlp

"I want to go swimming next Tuesday"
I want to machine to learn the date I want to go swimming. Is there any approaches or libraries that can

1. Extract "next Tuesday"
2. And calculate the exact date?

Comment: Try Google's [dialogflow api](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#date_and_time).

Answer (score 2):

There is a Python library called [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that will accept a wide variety of formats, including relative dates like "next Tuesday", and return exact `datetime` representation.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution as a service can be using [Microsoft LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/). In LUIS, you can use a prebuilt datetimeV2 entity which recognizes dates, times, date ranges and time durations. To know more about this prebuilt entity see [the documentation](http://recognizes%20dates,%20times,%20date%20ranges%20and%20time%20durations.).

Answer (score 0):

I will list possible ways to approach you problem:

A- Naïve approach

1. Save current date
2. Extract day from string using regex and extract its rank in the week (example 0 for Monday 1 for Tuesday and/or so)
3. Find preceding word to output 3
4. If output 3 is "Next" --> exact date = date for the output from 2 in the next calendar week
5. If output 3 is "on"/"this" --> exact date = date for the output from 2 in the this calendar week.

If you are using python, you will need `re` and `calendar` packages.

Pros:

1. Fast in developing
2. Sufficient for most of the cases

Cons:

1. Slow in implementation, depending on how long is the length of text
2. You have to account for all possible scenarios in output 4 above

B- Classification

Create a ground truth of strings with positive and negative examples and feed it into a classifier to learn from those examples.

You would need to parse the text first as a pre-processing step (but this would be the case for most approaches, isn't it?)

Pros:

1. Fast in implementation
2. Less rule-based
3. Accuracy is expected to be
   high depending on the classifier

Cons:

1. Creating ground truth is a time consuming (could be minimised by combining this approach with the Naïve one or with some `nlp`)
2. LWill need time to train (but this is shouldn't be too long)

C- Do it the Apple way

Have a look at some information on the [Apple Data Detectors](http://www.miramontes.com/writing/add-cacm/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the question.

To solve the first problem, you can use something called **Named Entity Recognition** . The problem of finding date is actually a sub problem of the more general **NER problem** . Nevertheless , you can try the awesome [Spacy NER Finder](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities) .

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'I want to go swimming next Tuesday')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text , ent.label_)
```

next Tuesday DATE

> The code finds all the named entities in the text. You can filter out
>   your relevant DATE entity if you get more than one kind of entity

The second problem is a bit simpler, once you have the DATE entity , its only a matter of your Python abilities. You can go by the following:

- Get the DATE entity
- Save the current date and day .
- Determine how many days you need to add to the current date by comparing today's day and the extracted day from the text.
- Add the no. of days to Today's date to get the desired date